# Demeaned Returns for Covariance (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, statistics, covariance

I've got this code:

```
function [sigma,shrinkage]=covMarket(x,shrink)

% function sigma=covmarket(x)
% x (t*n): t iid observations on n random variables
% sigma (n*n): invertible covariance matrix estimator
%
% This estimator is a weighted average of the sample
% covariance matrix and a "prior" or "shrinkage target".
% Here, the prior is given by a one-factor model.
% The factor is equal to the cross-sectional average
% of all the random variables.

% The notation follows Ledoit and Wolf (2003)
% This version: 04/2014



% de-mean returns
t=size(x,1);
n=size(x,2);
meanx=mean(x);
x=x-meanx(ones(t,1),:);
xmkt=mean(x')';

sample=cov([x xmkt])*(t-1)/t;
covmkt=sample(1:n,n+1);
varmkt=sample(n+1,n+1);
sample(:,n+1)=[];
sample(n+1,:)=[];
prior=covmkt*covmkt'./varmkt;
prior(logical(eye(n)))=diag(sample);

if (nargin < 2 | shrink == -1) % compute shrinkage parameters
 c=norm(sample-prior,'fro')^2;
  y=x.^2;
  p=1/t*sum(sum(y'*y))-sum(sum(sample.^2));
  % r is divided into diagonal
  % and off-diagonal terms, and the off-diagonal term
  % is itself divided into smaller terms 
  rdiag=1/t*sum(sum(y.^2))-sum(diag(sample).^2);
  z=x.*xmkt(:,ones(1,n));
   v1=1/t*y'*z-covmkt(:,ones(1,n)).*sample;
  roff1=sum(sum(v1.*covmkt(:,ones(1,n))'))/varmkt...
      -sum(diag(v1).*covmkt)/varmkt;
  v3=1/t*z'*z-varmkt*sample;
   roff3=sum(sum(v3.*(covmkt*covmkt')))/varmkt^2 ...
      -sum(diag(v3).*covmkt.^2)/varmkt^2;
  roff=2*roff1-roff3;
   r=rdiag+roff;
   % compute shrinkage constant
  k=(p-r)/c;
  shrinkage=max(0,min(1,k/t))
else % use specified number
  shrinkage = shrink;
end

% compute the estimator
sigma=shrinkage*prior+(1-shrinkage)*sample;

end
```

It's a Part of the Matlab code from [Ledoit/Wolf (2003)](http://www.econ.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:ffffffff-935a-b0d6-ffff-ffff9961f70f/jef.pdf). I don't understand why the demeaning the returns before calculating the covariance? Is this Matlab specific? In my opinion, there is no need for demeaning returns before calculating with the cov-function. (The function does it on its own)

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Maybe it did not in 2013.

Comment: ah that was a mistake. It was 2003. Yeah maybe, but the newest code is from 2014. And the Covariance is calculated the same since years.

Comment: Are you asking us if someone did a mistake writing code in 2003? What is the question

Comment: I don't think there is a mistake. I want to implement this code in R. But i don't understand the demeaning. I try to understand what i code.

Comment: 1) you haven't given is the source, reference things properly else we can not find them! 2)there is nothing else extra to understand than what is covariance and corrected covariance and you seem to understand that.

Comment: I mean, likely, they want the biased covariance, but matlab gives the normalised covariance instead, so the fix that.

Comment: Thanks i updated the sources. That's is n idea. I will follow on that.